# How does socket.io get arguments from the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have the following code on the server side:

```
var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('made socket connection with ID:', socket.id);
});
```

Here is what I understand.

We make a socket on the server side and pass that (instance?) to io. Then, we say io.on('connection') which is saying listen to the connection event. We also make a callback function to which we are passing socket.

I don't understand the callback function(socket) part. Where are we passing it socket? on the client side I have this

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
```

I get that a connection will be made and it will start listening but how and where are we calling the function form the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not calling the callback, and so we are not passing it anything. You can't call a serverside function from the clientside.

The callback is called (and given the argument) by the JavaScript's event loop, as triggered by socket.io library's internals - more specifically, as far as I can see, in [Engine.io](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/b1fa020675d905905b6f07d0a6b5acff775c4be5/lib/server.js#L341):

```
Server.prototype.handshake = function (transportName, req) {
  ...
  self.emit('connection', socket);
  ...
};
```

This is done through Node's native [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter), which allows you to [register a callback](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d022cb1bdd20f10483cbe988a950548df2dfd48c/lib/events.js#L172) for an event (`io.on('connection', function(socket) { ... })`), and [emit the event](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d022cb1bdd20f10483cbe988a950548df2dfd48c/lib/events.js#L131) with data for the callback (`self.emit('connection', socket)`). The data passed with the event emission is the data received by any callback registered for the event on the emitter object.

Thus, the flow is roughly as follows:

- Serverside, you register a callback handler for the `connection` event on the Engine.io object (passed to you by Socket.io's `socket` function).
- Clientside, you invoke the `connect` function. It starts a Websocket request.
- Serverside, Engine.io receives the Websocket request. It creates a `socket` object to represent the connection with that particular client, then emits the `connection` event, with the `socket` object as accompanying data.
- The `connection` event causes all handlers registered for that event to be invoked, and passed the accompanying data (the `socket` object), your function being among them.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. This is the answer (it is pretty complicated sounding. Maybe I need more lessons on basics)